# Should T be a parameter, a function, or what?

Tags: variables, math, symbolic-math

I'm new here and I don't really know how to precisely ask my question. I have to prepare code that will proceed like `x1 = x0 + t* e`, which in practice looks like:

```
x1 = [0.5, 1] + [0, t]

x1 = [0.5, 1+t]
```

How should I declare `t` to make it work? I mean `t` has to remain here all the time, to make it possible to calculate the roots of a quadratic function a few steps further.

Comment: That's no way c++ code!

Answer (score 0):

This would be hard to implement in a general purpose programming language because you need `t` to stay "symbolic" so you can do algebraic manipulations with it. You should look into implementing this in a Computer Algebra System (CAS) because those are specifically designed to handle symbolic computations. Implementing what you describe would be very quick and easy in a CAS.

There is well-known (and expensive proprietary) CAS software like [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) or [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/). Or if you are working in C++ or python there is [SymbolicC++](http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html) and [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) that integrate well with each of them respectively. You can see Wikipedia for a [list of CAS software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).